# Laravel 5.1 Sort the result of a search filter

Tags: sorting, filter, laravel-5

I have searched the site and I can choose various filters. This already works. He returns and makes pagination correctly.

Example:

```
/empresas?estado=2&tipo=3&page=2
```

The problem is when I click to order (one form select).

It does not maintain the current URL, it simply does:

```
/empresas?ordenar=nome
```

It should be something like:

```
/empresas?estado=2&tipo=3&ordenar=nome&page=3
```

I made an append such as paging does.

But it did not work.

The Controller:

```
$estados = DB::table('estados')->orderBy('nome', 'asc')->get();
$tipos = DB::table('tipos')->orderBy('nome', 'asc')->get();

$word = Input::get('query');
$ordenar = Input::get('ordenar');
$estado = Input::get('estado');
$tipo = Input::get('tipo');

$query = Empresas::with('usuario')
    ->with('estado');

if($word)
    $query->where('descricao', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
        ->orWhere('carta', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%');

if($estado)
    $query->whereIn('estado_id', $estado);

if($tipo)
    $query->where('tipo_id', $tipo);

if($ordenar)
    $query->orderby($ordenar, 'asc');

$empresas = $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(18);

return view("pages.empresas.index")
    ->with('estados', $estados)
    ->with('tipos', $tipos)
    ->with(compact('empresas', 'word', 'ordenar', 'estado','tipo'));
```

In VIEW:

I make a foreach bringing the fields normally and the phaco append to render that already works

```
<center>{!! str_replace('/?','?', $empresas->appends(Input::query())->render()) !!}</center>
```

I have a form to sorting by perhaps the error is it

```
 <form action="/empresas" method=get>
     <select class="form-control m-b" name="ordenar" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Ordenar por...</option>
     <option value="nome">Nome</option>                                                       
     </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid these nasty if statements by using eloquent scopes/relationships.

Your error is simple you will need to add the other form elements you expect to see in the query string to the form. If you want to use hidden fields. You only see one parameter because you have only one input in your form.

Comment: Perfect, I can put in hidden fields.
But what if the paginate?
As he would order it, keeping the paginate?
do u undesrstand the problem? :(

Thank 

Sorry my english

Comment: Yeah i get you. I think just put the page into a hidden field as well would be easiest. I think maybe your design needs to change to be more 'laravel'. Lots of if's and hidden fields doesnt look like nice ... but if it works it works